# Sharepoint 2010 custom text layout

Tags: css, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'd like to make my custom page layout with two columns. The right column in the default text layout (also two columns) has a size of 33.3% and I'd like to have a fix width of 250px (in the right column)! How can I do this?

I use Sharepoint 2010 with a team site template.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have SharePoint 2010 Server you can use the publishing feature and create custom "layout pages". There are plenty tutorials on the web.

If you only have the free SharePoint 2010 Foundation you will not have access to the "Publishing feature". The pages in the Foundation version are typically stored in "Site Pages" library or in an other wiki library. You can change the layout by using the "Text Layout" button in the ribbon.

If you are a more advanced user and know how to use Visual Studio can also change these layouts by code.